# How is Gnome Software different to AppCenter?

Tags: release-loki, appcenter

I'm trying out elementary OS 0.4 Loki and so far I could install everything I wanted via PPA or an official Ubuntu .deb package without any problems.
 App Center isn't a great help so far... is there any documentation how AppCenter is different or better to Gnome Software what are the pros of AppCenter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not use AppCenter either. It's so buggy but good for update packages. When apt and synaptic works great there is no problem for me. I think there is no advantage at all, but it will be a cool tool in future. It is Ubuntu software center alternative designed according to OS design pattern. It is good to have it but without any bug.